# Help with Canada Post Shipping Quotes with Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

Is there someone that can help me with Canada Post Shipping Quotes with Ubercart?  I can't find any documentation on how to set it up.  I've gotten my Canada Post account and I've put all the information into the module, but it's not showing any quotes.  I also have UPS and it's displaying quotes just fine.  I'm not seeing any errors or anything so I'm wondering if I've missed a set up somewhere?  I tried going into the Canada Online setup but quite frankly I don't understand what I'm supposed to do.  Do I have to set up every possible package size for it to work?  How would that reference back to the product?  We sell so many different products that could be a nightmare!!!  If anyone can at least point me in the right direction I would be so grateful!!
Thanks!

Comment: Update... I did find some limited help at http://drupal.org/node/1776864#comment-7227240 but still no quotes or errors or messages saying it can't be completed. I phoned Canada Post and I have their end set up right - so I'm totally stuck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the store address information all filled out properly in the Ubercart Store Configuration and in the Shipping module.  It seems like a duplication but it helped me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment xylene, it was all correct.  I ended up hiring a PHP coder to fix the issue.  There was something in the actual module where it wasn't dealing with the province or city or something properly.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you were able to share more details concerning this.